# Parents' appreciation of the educational system

Tags: meaning, word-choice

[image: treat teachers]

> Although the parents do not think highly of the educational system as a whole, they fail to treat teachers with **opprobrium** equally

I don't understand the meaning of the sentence. I'll try to paraphraze it: Parents don't think too much about teachers and in general don't conside too much of the educational system. In spite of it they disdain the teachers, but some they hate more and some the humiliate less. Am I right?
I don't get the point of the sentence…

Comment: I don't get it either.  The mere fact that parents dislike the education system as a whole doesn't mean that treating individual teachers differently is a failure of some sort. Some teachers probably deserve more blame than others.

Comment: Where does this quote come from?   It makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

I would interpret that statement differently than previous answerers:

> The opprobium parents express toward the educational system they do not express toward teachers as a group.

The statement refers to a disliked system (education) and a specific group operating within that system (teachers) that is not disliked as much (if at all). It does not refer to individuals or to other groups than teachers operating within the system.

Comment: +1 : the bad opinion about the educational system doesn't extend to the teaching staff.

Answer (score 3):

Parents do not think highly of the educational system.

Parents criticise some teachers more than others.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible interpretations:

1. Parents treat some teachers differently from others.  That is, parents visit opprobrium, i.e., harsh criticism, in different measures for different teachers.  Some teachers are more harshly criticized than other teachers.
2. Parents treat teachers differently from other, non-teaching staff of the the "educational system" that they dislike.  The parents reserve opprobrium for the latter, and they do not visit such upon the former.

Comment: +1 But I’d bet money they meant your number 1 and not number 2.

Comment: @Jim This appears to be a GRE prep test question in which the test taker is to select from a list an appropriate word to follow *with*, the answer being *opprobrium*.  Thus the whole sentence doesn't really have an intended meaning.  Ordinarily, saying that a group is treated unequally means that the treatment varies over the individuals in the group.  But this is inapt with the introductory suborindate clause about the system "as a whole."